# ActiveAdmin 1.0.0.pre and Rails 4 CSS not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

My `ActiveAdmin` assets file is not included after I logged in in `ActiveAdmin`.
In logging page work fine.

I am using Ruby 2.1.1, Rails 4.0.4 and ActiveAdmin 1.0.0.pre master brunch on GitHub.

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'rails', '~> 4.0.4'
...
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'
```

**active_admin.css.scss** and **active_admin.js.coffee** is generated by `active_admin:assets`

After logging ActiveAdmin generated

```
<link href="/stylesheets/active_admin.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" /> etc...
```

instead

```
<link href="/assets/active_admin.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" /> etc...
```

This is bug or I doing something wrong?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be asked in active_admin issue tracker https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues

Comment: This must be a bug, facing same issue on heroku